# Tagging fans of a fanpage without user login. How can I work around this?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, desktop-application

As far as I know, you can only tag friends of the account associated with the access_token currently in use. This means that if I want to be able to make an app to share photos on facebook with a tagging functionality, it's mandatory that I make an authentication system, where the user needs to type his password to login on FB and I request and store his sixty_days_access_token. This approach is fine for web apps, but is troublesome if I have to implement a desktop touchscreen interface where the users interact with the system in an environment where anyone can watch him typing his user and password. I'm facing this problem with a public touchscreen, where the users can take pictures and send it to Facebook. The interface is implemented with C++ and the curl library. As the touch is in a very crowded environment and the screen is big, we experienced that the users are intimidated to enter his acc/pass. We worked around this problem by creating a fan page to the event where we store all the photos. As we already have the fan page admin access token stored, we don't need to login the users but clearly we are not able to tag any of the user friends, which vastly reduce the viralization potential of the solution.

So, having this problem in mind, how can I face this?

- Do I really need to make an authentication of the users to be able to
  tag their friends?
- Is there any creative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you want to tag a user or their friends in a post, you need them to log in - this is a requirement of the Photo tagging API.

The only alternative i can think of is to give the user a URL they can go to later (e.g. on their phone or PC) which will prompt them to authorise your app and do the tagging at that time.